# segmentation fault in c. Can anyone tell me how to solve it?

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me how can I solve the segmentation fault? I am still in a very early session of the class. I know that the segmentation fault has to do with my array and variable "storedplain". My intention was to create an array with int type and then store all the char variables that the user typed as int for my code in the next steps.

```
    string plaintext = get_string(" plaintext: ");    
    int storedplain[] = {0};

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
        {
            char conversion2 = plaintext[i];
            storedplain[i] = conversion2;
        }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: The size of `int storedplain[] = {0};` is 1 element. So you can't store any string data there. In C arrays do not automatically resize.

Comment: Are you using the CS50 library? If the answer is yes, then please additionally tag your question with the "cs50" tag.

Comment: My guess is that the assignment  is to count letter frequency. In that case you need an array size 128 which is indexed by the letter, for example `lettercount[ plaintext[i] ]`

Comment: `int storedplain[] = {0};` is broken because it reserves space for just one element, and you plainly want to use more than one element in that array. But a correct fix is unclear because you have not described what the code is supposed to do. You should never describe a problem merely as a “segment fault”; that is insufficient information. A bug in a program is a deviation from its specification. So, to fully diagnose a bug or to know how to design the program correctly, people need to know the specification of the program, a statement of what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: Also note that the end of a string is indicated by an implicit null byte (`'\0'`) at the end, *which is not included in the number returned by `strlen()`*. So you likely want to loop to `strlen( plaintext ) + 1`. Also, signedness of `char` is implementation-defined. Standard practice in C when handling characters as integers (like e.g. `isalpha()`) is to *cast the `char` to `unsigned`*. This gets important when you are going to compare / sort those converted characters later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int storedplain[] = {0};` is the same as `int storedplain[1] = {0};`.

This means `storedplain[i] = conversion2` will write past the end of `storedplain` since `i < strlen(plaintext)` will result in a value for `i` larger than 0.

A solution would be something along the line of `int storedplain[MAX_STRING] = {0};`. This could only work if you know the max string size that can be returned.

The best solution is to use `malloc()`:
`int * storedplain = malloc(strlen(plaintext) * sizeof(int));`

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I write an array with no specific number of data within it? Should it be like int storedplain[ ];  or int storedplain [ ] = { };

Comment: *array with no specific number of data* - That is a pointer and `malloc()`. C arrays are fixed size.